# How to properly clear an entire binary tree in Java?

Tags: java, binary-tree

I have simple binary search tree class with instance variable of type Node which is the root. This is nothing complicated, just the same basic BST class you have seen before with a Node class with a field for the type of data and two references to left and right nodes. I want a method that clears the tree. Originally, I thought, ok here it is:

```
void clearTree() { root = null; }
```

but my professor claims that this does not really clear the tree from memory since there are still references to nodes from the parent nodes in the tree... Even though we don't have references to them. Is he correct to say this? If yes, why does this not clear the tree from memory? I thought that once we lose our reference to it, it would be garbage collected.

Comment: Are you exposing `root` outside your `BinarySearchTree` class?

Comment: No, root is only exposed in the BinarySearchTree class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your professor is right in the way that making the root equal to null will not free the entire tree. In languages like C, if you make `root=null` the entire tree still in the memory.

But in Java, as @radai said, the Garbage Collector will clean it for you once you don't have any more references to the tree nodes. So, in Java context, make `root=null` will work.

Anyway, if you do need to clean every single node of the tree (what is needed in C/C++ languages, for example) you can use the pos-order algorithm. Of course, you will need to adapt the algorithm to your variable names and structs (or classes, if you want to apply it in Java).

```
void clearTree(treenode *node) {
    if (node != NULL) {
        clearTree( node->leftChild );
        clearTree( node->rightChild );
        delete( node ); // Or in Java, node = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

anything you cannot reach anymore (through any reference/pointer in your code) is eligible for garbage collection.

so , assuming you didnt keep any references to any other Nodes except the root node reference, the entire tree is up for GC the minute you null-out the root reference.

if you really want to prove this to your prof, i suggest you get a copy of [eclipse memory analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/), take a snapshot right after nulling-out the field (using the hprof command line utility thats bundled with the jdk, have your code sleep for 20 seconds so its easy to catch) and then you can prove that there are no strongly reachable Nodes in memory

Comment: Yes, I only have the reference to the root.

Answer (score 0):

I think your professor might be wrong. Consider a composite object `A`:

```
class A {
   private B b;
   private C c;

   public A(B b, C c){
     this.b = b;
     this.c = c;
   }

}
```

and we use it as:

```
A a = new A(new B(), new C());
```

When you do:

```
a = null;
```

The object that was referenced by `a` will be garbage collected and with it any other parts of the object (if they are not referenced elsewhere). This happens all the time and we don't even think about it.

And I believe it is the same thing with the tree. It will recursively claim the other object impossible to reach. IF there are no other references to that root.

**EDIT:**

A gif showing how GC decides whether object is reachable: [here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/4a/Animation_of_the_Naive_Mark_and_Sweep_Garbage_Collector_Algorithm.gif/220px-Animation_of_the_Naive_Mark_and_Sweep_Garbage_Collector_Algorithm.gif)